# creating two outputs with Makefile

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile, openmp, gnu-make

I want to create a makefile which runs program in C++ once with "CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -g -O3 -DTEST -fopenmp" and one time with: "CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -g -O3 -fopenmp"
at the end outputs two different files like P1-Test and P1. how can I edit this file?

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -g -O3 -fopenmp

ifdef code_coverage
    GCOV_FLAG :=  -DTEST
else
    GCOV_FLAG :=
endif

all: P1
        @echo The program has been compiled

# implicit rule: create x from x.cpp
.cpp:
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $? -o $@
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(GCOV_FLAG) $? -o $@
.PHONY: clean
clean:
        $(RM) -r P1 *.dSYM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -g -O3 -fopenmp

all: P1 P1-Test
    @echo The program has been compiled

# implicit rule: create x from x.cpp
.cpp:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $? -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) -r P1 *.dSYM

P1: main.o second.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o "$@" $^

P1-Test: CXXFLAGS+=-DTEST
P1-Test: main.o second.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o "$@" $^
```

With sample sources:

- File `main.cpp`

  ```
   extern void foo(); // should be in second.h or something

   int main() { foo(); }
  ```
- File `second.cpp`

  ```
   #include <cstdio>

   void foo() {
   #ifdef TEST
       puts("TEST defined");
   #else
       puts("TEST not defined");
   #endif
   }
  ```

Results in

```
$ make -B
g++ -std=c++11 -g -O3 -fopenmp -o "P1" main.cpp second.cpp 
g++ -std=c++11 -g -O3 -fopenmp -DTEST -o "P1-Test" main.cpp second.cpp 
The program has been compiled
```

And of course the outputs:

```
./P1; ./P1-Test 
TEST not defined
TEST defined
```

### Alternative

If your `.o` files are really .PRECIOUS, you might want to build separate copies. Here I split into `release/main.o` and `test/main.o`:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -g -O3 -fopenmp

all: P1 P1-Test
    @echo The program has been compiled

test/%.o: CXXFLAGS+=-DTEST
test/%.o: %.cpp
    mkdir -pv $(@D)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $? -c -o $@

release/%.o: %.cpp
    mkdir -pv $(@D)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $? -c -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) -rfv P1 P1-Test *.dSYM release/ test/

P1: release/main.o release/second.o
P1-Test: test/main.o test/second.o

P1 P1-Test:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o "$@" $^ $(LDFLAGS)
```

Which gives:

```
mkdir -pv release
g++ -std=c++11 -g -O3 -fopenmp main.cpp -c -o release/main.o
mkdir -pv release
g++ -std=c++11 -g -O3 -fopenmp second.cpp -c -o release/second.o
g++ -std=c++11 -g -O3 -fopenmp -o "P1" release/main.o release/second.o 
mkdir -pv test
g++ -std=c++11 -g -O3 -fopenmp -DTEST main.cpp -c -o test/main.o
mkdir -pv test
g++ -std=c++11 -g -O3 -fopenmp -DTEST second.cpp -c -o test/second.o
g++ -std=c++11 -g -O3 -fopenmp -o "P1-Test" test/main.o test/second.o 
echo The program has been compiled
```

Comment: Added an alternative version that keeps .o files between builds.